# Crear un encabezado desde un atributo rel con css

Tags: css

Holas, estoy tratando de crear un encabezado dentro de un bloque pre a través de su atributo rel, algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como verán en la imagen tiene un encabezado con el texto HTML, algo así quiero lograr pero no he podido, este es mi código pre:

```
pre.block,
{
background-color: #fafafa !important;
/*-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px;
-ms-border-radius: 4px;
-khtml-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;*/
color: #000000;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
overflow: auto;
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 13px;
width: 95%;
white-space: pre-wrap;
font-family: Consolas, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Andale Mono", Monaco, "DejaVu Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", monospace;
}
```

Intenté hacer un :after pero el texto me quedaba muy lejos del contenedor, ¿se podrá hacer o habrá una mejor manera de hacerlo?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes simplificarlo más que eso.
Crea un div contenedor al que le das el formato general y a la cabecera prácticamente no tendrás que darle más que los colores:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Consolas, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono";
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #9c6031;
}
.header
{
  background-color: #399c42;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.content
{
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">HTML</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum....</div>
</div>
```

También podrías aplicarle si quieres un degradado.
Puedes echarle un vistazo a este artículo:
[CSS3. Degradados lineales](http://pildorasjs.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/css3-degradados-lineales.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya lo adapté y queda perfecto! gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer usando el pseudo-elemento `::before` (te hará la vida más fácil que `::after` si lo que quieres es un título) sin necesidad de crear ninguna etiqueta adicional. Con `content:attr(nombre-de-atributo)` puedes leer el nombre que se pondrá en el título, y definirlo como un bloque para que ocupe todo el ancho del contenedor.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo (le pongo márgenes negativos porque he puesto padding al `pre` para que se parezca más a la imagen que has puesto):

```css
pre {
  background:#222222;
  color:#CC9900;
  padding:8px;
}

pre::before {
  content:attr(rel);
  display:block;
  background:green;
  color:white;
  margin:-8px -8px 8px -8px;
  padding:8px;
}
```

```html
<pre rel="CSS">
p { color:red; }
</pre>
```